# Some questions about the export of the template from a website and the import of it into another website

Tags: content-management-system, typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I have installed TYPO3 on my web server and it use the "Introduction Package" template.

The problem is that I have to work on another TYPO3 online website that use a custom template.

Can I obtain the template of the online website and use it on my local website? (to perform some test in local).

I saw that TYPO3 uses various templating systems and I do not know how this could affect the export\import operation. In Joomla or WP I simply take the template directory and then I copy it into the themes directory but I think that in TYPO3 this operation could be more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way is to copy these directories:

```
fileadmin
uploads
typo3conf/ext
```

and the complete database, then you have "cloned" the original website locally. (assuming that the core stuff is loaded the default way, with symlinks)

Then you just need to edit the database connection stuff and maybe some paths for image magick and so on in the `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php`.